# visual studio crash on package manager console run of script-migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

My setup:

- VS Community 2019 v16.5.4
- .NET Core 3.1
- Microsoft.Entity.FrameworkCore.Tools v3.1.3
- Microsoft.Entity.FrameworkCore.SqlServer v3.1.3

As recommended by Microsoft, using package manager console tools to run add-migration (which was successful) and script-migration (which failed, and caused VS to crash).
[EF Core Tools Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet)

I have searched through entity framework core on stackoverflow and on github with no success in finding fix for VS crash.

I was successful in getting migration script by running from CLI dotnet ef migrations script

Posting this in case others experience similar problem or have found a fix.